# Is it possible to make incremental local backups for Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos, linux

I'm considering to use Google Photos as primary storage for my photos, because I use multiple devices, and it makes sense to use centralized cloud service.

I really don't like an idea to have have by photos stored only at one place. And, I want to have local backups of my photos (on external HDD).

Downloading few GBs of same photos regularly doesn't make much sense. Therefore I consider to make incremental regular backups (photos uploaded in past N-days/N-weeks), and only occasionally full backups.

Requirements - supported platforms: both Windows and Linux, or directly from web (no native application, works on all platforms)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The OP updated that he's working with Linux. Keeping it for Windows users that will arrive here.

---

For Windows, there's the [Google Photos Backup Tool](https://photos.google.com/apps)

It would sync your photos and can be set to sync the photos in high or original quality.

Comment: There's no Linux version? :-(

Comment: Oh, it seems not. Would you update the question with the details on your OS and environment? anything that can be useful

Comment: I have updated the question